# Unable to create property file using Ant script

Tags: ant

I am trying to create a new Property File with the below snippet of Ant script.

```
<propertyfile file="${path}/sample.properties">
                  <entry  key="k1" value="v1"/>
</propertyfile>
```

It tries create the property file and I get the below error

(The system cannot find the path specified). Here the path includes the file name as well. I confirmed the parent folder where the property files needs to be created exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a build file with your snippet and couldn't see an issue. If the directory specified by the path property doesn't exist an exception is thrown but this seems like the correct behaviour.

I suggest you add some tests to confirm the actual value of the path property.  Maybe it doesn't hold the value you expect.

**build.xml**

```
<project>
<property name="path" value="./test"/>
<propertyfile file="${path}/sample.properties">
                  <entry  key="k1" value="v1"/>
</propertyfile>
</project>
```

**Test Case 1 - 'test' directory not present - expected result FAIL**

```
$ ls test
ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory
$ ant build.xml
Buildfile: /home/owen/stackoverflow/build.xml
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/owen/stackoverflow/test/sample.properties

BUILD FAILED
/home/owen/stackoverflow/build.xml:3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/owen/stackoverflow/test/sample.properties (No such file or directory)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

**Test Case 2 - 'test' directory now available - expected result SUCCESS**

```
$ mkdir test
$ ant
Buildfile: /home/owen/stackoverflow/build.xml
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /home/owen/stackoverflow/test/sample.properties

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry didn't read the section mentioning that the parent folder exists. For me the given snippet works (in Eclipse). What does your `path` variable contains and which environment you use exactly ?

All folders specified by your `path` variable must exist before Ant can create the property file, even before any target is executed.